# What is Dalvik Debug Monitoring Service?

Tags: android, dalvik

I am confused DDMS.

please someone answer the following questions.

- what exactly is Dalvik Debug Monitoring Service?
- why is it compulsory for Android SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The Dalvik Debug Monitor Service (DDMS) is a debugging tool used in the Android platform. The Dalvik Debug Monitor Service is downloaded as part of the Android SDK. Some of the services provided by the DDMS are port forwarding, on-device screen capture, on-device thread and heap monitoring, and radio state information.

**EXPLANATION** 
The Dalvik Debug Monitor Service allows developers to spot bugs in applications running on either an emulator or an actual Android device.

For example, by using the DDMS’ LogCat feature, developers can view log messages regarding the state of the application and the device. LogCat can pinpoint the exact line number on which an error occurred.

Another DDMS feature, known as the Emulator Control, allows developers to simulate phone states and activities. For example, it can simulate different types of networks such as GPRS, EDGE, and UTMS, which can have different network characteristics such as speed and latency.

Aside from the features mentioned earlier, the Dalvik Debug Monitor Service also provides LogCat, process, and radio state information as well as incoming call, SMS, and location data spoofing.

This debugging tool can be integrated into the Eclipse IDE by adding the ADT (Android Development Tools) plug-in. Otherwise, it can be accessed from the command line and will automatically connect to any running emulator.

Comment: Official docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html .  Design doc (completely out of date): http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugmon.html .  FWIW, it's "server", not "service".